# Calculating RSI for recent days

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm working on improving my algo bot and one thing that I have implemented absolutely awful is RSI. Since RSI is a lagging indicator I can't get recent data, the last date I get a value for is 8 days ago. I'm therefore looking to calculate it somehow by using previous values and looking for ideas on how to do so.

My data points:

```
[222.19000244140625, nan]
[222.19000244140625, nan]
[215.47000122070312, nan]
[212.25, nan]
[207.97000122070312, nan]
[206.3300018310547, nan]
[205.88999938964844, nan]
[208.36000061035156, nan]
[204.08999633789062, 10.720487433358727]
[197.00999450683594, 7.934105468501102]
[194.6699981689453, 7.224811311424375]
[190.66000366210938, 6.148330770309926]
[191.6300048828125, 9.861218420857213]
[189.13999938964844, 8.835726925023536]
[189.02000427246094, 8.785409465194874]
[187.02000427246094, 7.925663008903896]
[195.69000244140625, 37.989974096922204]
[196.9199981689453, 41.10776671337689]
[194.11000061035156, 36.33757785797855]
```

As you can see 10.720487433358727 is my most recent value but I'm sure bigger brains than mine can figure out a way to calculate it up until today.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It appears to me that the bottom value (36.33757785797855) may be the latest RSI value.

Comment: @C.Pappy Do you mean that it's the most recent by that? 222.19000244140625 is the most recent value, i.e yesterdays closing and 194.11000061035156 is 15+ days ago

Comment: Without seeing your code, yes,  suspect that is correct.

Comment: How if it's the oldest data point..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that there are various ways of defining the RSI. It is commonly defined in at least two ways: using a simple moving average (SMA) as above, or using an exponential moving average (EMA). Here's a code snippet that calculates both definitions of RSI and plots them for comparison. I'm discarding the first row after taking the difference, since it is always NaN by definition.

```
import pandas
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Window length for moving average
window_length = 14

# Dates
start = '2020-12-01'
end = '2021-01-27'

# Get data
data = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start, end)
# Get just the adjusted close
close = data['Adj Close']
# Get the difference in price from previous step
delta = close.diff()
# Get rid of the first row, which is NaN since it did not have a previous 
# row to calculate the differences
delta = delta[1:] 

# Make the positive gains (up) and negative gains (down) Series
up, down = delta.copy(), delta.copy()
up[up < 0] = 0
down[down > 0] = 0

# Calculate the EWMA
roll_up1 = up.ewm(span=window_length).mean()
roll_down1 = down.abs().ewm(span=window_length).mean()

# Calculate the RSI based on EWMA
RS1 = roll_up1 / roll_down1
RSI1 = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + RS1))

# Calculate the SMA
roll_up2 = up.rolling(window_length).mean()
roll_down2 = down.abs().rolling(window_length).mean()

# Calculate the RSI based on SMA
RS2 = roll_up2 / roll_down2
RSI2 = 100.0 - (100.0 / (1.0 + RS2))

# Compare graphically
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
RSI1.plot()
RSI2.plot()
plt.legend(['RSI via EWMA', 'RSI via SMA'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Glad I could help